# Should Getters and Setters in Kotlin be the same as Java in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, oop, firebase-realtime-database

This Model class has getters and setters implemented the same as in Java but now written in Kotlin

```
 class HousePost{
private var uid: String = ""
private var postImage: String = ""
private var rent: String = ""
private var description: String = ""
private var publisher: String = ""
private var location: String = ""
private var postId: String? = ""
private var rooms: String = ""
private var caption: String = ""
private var dateTime: String = ""
var expandable: Boolean = false

constructor()
constructor(
   uid: String,
   postImage: String,
   rent: String,
   description: String,
   location: String,
   postId: String,
   publisher: String,
   rooms: String,
   caption: String,
   dateTime : String
) {
   this.uid = uid
   this.postImage = postImage
   this.rent = rent
   this.description = description
   this.location = location
   this.postId = postId
   this.publisher = publisher
   this.rooms = rooms
   this.caption = caption
   this.dateTime = dateTime
   this.expandable = false
}
//Post Details getters
fun getUid() : String {
   return uid
}
fun getPostId (): String? {
   return postId
}
fun getPostImage():String {
   return postImage
}
fun getDescription():String {
   return description
}
fun getLocation():String {
   return location
}
fun getRent():String {
   return rent
}
fun getPublisher(): String {
   return publisher
}

fun getRooms(): String {
   return rooms
}
fun getCaption() : String {
   return caption
}
fun getDateTime() : String {
   return dateTime
}

//Post Details setters
fun setUid (uid: String) {
   this.uid = uid
}
fun setPostId(postId: String) {
   this.postId = postId
}
fun setPostImage(postImage: String) {
   this.postImage = postImage
}
fun setLocation(location: String) {
   this.location = location
}
fun setDescription(description: String) {
   this.description = description
}
fun setRent(rent: String) {
   this.rent = rent
}
fun setPublisher(publisher: String) {
   this.publisher = publisher
}
fun setCaption(caption: String) {
   this.caption = caption
}
fun setDateTime(dateTime: String) {
   this.dateTime = dateTime
}
```

}

This class is supposed to model data from my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7fxV.png). Is that the correct way in Kotlin?
There is a *No setter/field for class found* error I'm getting. My recyclerview does not show the data at all, I assume is due to the error.

Comment: It's not correct way in kotlin. Read more about it here https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/getters-setters
It looks like that class was simply rewritten from java to kotlin by an automatic tool or by someone who didn't know how kotlin works

Comment: I don't get how I will be able to get the data as modelled from my database and display it in a recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, a property doesn’t require explicit getter or setter methods.

[Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html) in Kotlin classes can be declared either as mutable, using the `var` keyword, or as read-only, using the `val` keyword.

A class whose main purpose is to hold data in Kotlin these are called [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) and are marked with `data`.
For example in your case the class can be define as below:

```
data class HousePost(
    val uid: String = ""
    val postImage: String = ""
    val rent: String = ""
    val description: String = ""
    val publisher: String = ""
    val location: String = ""
    val postId: String? = ""
    val rooms: String = ""
    val caption: String = ""
    val dateTime: String = ""
    val expandable: Boolean = false
)
```

The `val` keyword make the properties of this data class immutable. It means that you cannot change its properties after initialized.

To make a property mutable you can use `var`.

For example:

```
val housePost = HousePost() // This will use all the default value
housePost.expandable = true // Val cannot be reassigned
```

To make expandable mutable use `var` like so:

```
data class HousePost(
    .
    .
    .
    var expandable: Boolean = false
)

val housePost = HousePost()
housePost.expandable = true // Can be reassigned
```

**Edit**

You got the error(No setter/field for class found error) because you mark the class property private. You can simply fix it by removing private, the constructor, getters and setters in your current class.

There are other ways to define a property in a class. You will get to know how to use them as you learn.

```
class HousePost {
    var uid: String = ""
    var postImage: String = ""
    var rent: String = ""
    var description: String = ""
    var publisher: String = ""
    var location: String = ""
    var postId: String? = ""
    var rooms: String = ""
    var caption: String = ""
    var dateTime: String = ""
    var expandable: Boolean = false
}
```

Or this:

```
class HousePost (
    var uid: String = ""
    var postImage: String = ""
    var rent: String = ""
    var description: String = ""
    var publisher: String = ""
    var location: String = ""
    var postId: String? = ""
    var rooms: String = ""
    var caption: String = ""
    var dateTime: String = ""
    var expandable: Boolean = false
)
```

Comment: After I modified my HousePost class to a Data Class it worked. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**You just simple do this. Remove the functions, it's not usable**

```
class HousePost {
    private var uid: String = ""
    private var postImage: String = ""
    private var rent: String = ""
    private var description: String = ""
    private var publisher: String = ""
    private var location: String = ""
    private var postId: String? = ""
    private var rooms: String = ""
    private var caption: String = ""
    private var dateTime: String = ""
    var expandable: Boolean = false

    constructor()
    constructor(uid: String,
                postImage: String,
                rent: String,
                description: String,
                location: String,
                postId: String,
                publisher: String,
                rooms: String,
                caption: String,
                dateTime: String) {
        this.uid = uid
        this.postImage = postImage
        this.rent = rent
        this.description = description
        this.location = location
        this.postId = postId
        this.publisher = publisher
        this.rooms = rooms
        this.caption = caption
        this.dateTime = dateTime
        this.expandable = false
    }
}
```

Comment: If i remove the functions, how will i be able to access the properties and get their data in my recyclerview?

Comment: @SamKabiru just do some kotlin tutorials, you will get it.

Comment: @SamKabiru  holder.userId.text = mList[position].uid

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin provides default `getters` and `setters` for `properties`, you don't have to manually define them.

In Kotlin

```
var data: String = ""
```

is equivalent as

```
var data: String = ""
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```

because Kotlin compiler generates it for you. But if you only want to make your `getter` `public` but not `setter`, then you can override `setter`

```
var data: String = ""
    private set
```

You can do the same for the `getter` too.

---

> This class is supposed to model data from my database. Is that the
> correct way in Kotlin?

No, that is not the correct way to define a model class in Kotlin. Kotlin provides `data` classes, whose main function is to hold data. `Data class` primary constructor needs at least one parameter.

So, your model class can be refactored like this

```
data class HousePost(
    var uid: String = "",
    var postImage: String = "",
    var rent: String = "",
    var description: String = "",
    var publisher: String = "",
    var location: String = "",
    var postId: String? = "",
    var rooms: String = "",
    var caption: String = "",
    var dateTime: String = "",
    var expandable: Boolean = false
)
```

In any case, if you need only private setters for any field, you can make that `constructor` property `private`, and then make a public property that delegates to this private field.

```
data class HousePost(
    private var _uid: String = "",
    var postImage: String = "",
    var rent: String = "",
    var description: String = "",
    var publisher: String = "",
    var location: String = "",
    var postId: String? = "",
    var rooms: String = "",
    var caption: String = "",
    var dateTime: String = "",
    var expandable: Boolean = false
) {
    val uid: String get() = _uid
}
```